# Graphviz can't find any fonts

Tags: linux, fonts, graph, graphviz, dot

I'm getting "Could not find/open font" errors when doing anything with graphviz. I've been narrowing it down to an as simple graph as possible, in the file `simplest.dot`:

```
digraph G {
  node1
}
```

When running `$ dot simplest.dot -Tpng -O` the graph is rendered to `simplest.dot.png`, but I always get this error: `Error: Could not find/open font`, and the font used in the output isn't very pretty.

According to the graphviz faq, when this error occurs, you can [tell graphviz where to look for fonts](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/FAQ.html#Q37). I've been looking around for fonts on the system I'm using, and there seem to be some TrueType fonts in `/usr/share/fonts`, among others, the Bitstream Vera fonts, which seem to live in `/usr/share/fonts/bitstream-vera`.

So I've tried setting `fontpath` and `fontname` in the dot graph, to help graphviz figure things out:

```
digraph G {
  fontpath="/usr/share/fonts/bitstream-vera"
  fontname="Bitstream Vera Sans"
  node1
}
```

But I'm still getting the exact same error. I've tried several variations of the path and font name, but I can't seem to get it right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a shot into the dark, but in http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:fontname it says *If you specify fontname=schlbk, the tool will look for a file named schlbk.ttf or schlbk.pfa or schlbk.pfb in one of the directories specified by the fontpath attribute.*

So, I'd probably try

```
digraph G {
  fontpath="/usr/share/fonts/bitstream-vera"
  fontname="nameOfttfWITHOUTsuffix.ttf"
  node1
}
```

Comment: It actually seems like this works! I kinda feel stupid for not trying this myself. Thanks!

Comment: Having to add a font configuration in each project is okay but it'd be nicer to fix the tool itself.

Comment: These settings don't work everywhere. Please read https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/blob/master/doc/fontfaq.txt for more details.

Answer (score 0):

On my macOS, the following works:

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=plaintext, fontname="SourceCodePro"];
```